# How much does annual maintenance of a vibration table cost?

Tags: testing, vibration

The company I work for produces hardware for spacecraft and we routinely have to test that hardware to ensure it meets the stringent requirements for random vibration environments on the missions they are destined for.  Up until now we've been using services out of house to conduct these tests but we are considering buying the equipment to have more flexibility to do the testing on our schedule.

Does anyone know how much typical annual maintenance costs run for vibration tables?

Our equipment can be up to 200 kg so we're considering a moderately large table with both vertical and horizontal shake capability.

Comment: Beside the annual costs, have you already checked other requirements? Like the needed foundation? My former institute had a celler-room filled with concrete for a shaker capable of shaking 20 kg in the ground floor.

Comment: Yes, I did find some good articles about the facility mods recommended from several table manufacturers, but maintenance data has been hard to come by.  In addition to the foundation requirements, ventilation upgrades, noise isolation, and power requirements are expected.